# Definir sombra para criar efeito gradiente

Tags: css

Tenho uma lista ul / li e quero definir sombra para criar um efeito de gradiente quando li tiver ativo e com hover.

Esse é o código que cria a borda, a idéia é inserir mais 5px como sombra para criar o efeito.

```
ul.navmenu-nav>li>a:hover,
ul.navmenu-nav>li.active>a,
ul.navmenu-nav>li>a:focus {
   padding-left:15px;
   border-left: 5px solid #2E2F44;
   text-decoration: none;
   background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendo bem com linear-gradiente vc consegue fazer esse efeito.

Eu fiz o efeito degrade com 10px de largura, mas vc consegue controlar esse tamanho nos valores de inicio e fim do gradiente, deixem um comentário no código, nele sua cor começa no 0px e vai fazendo o gradiente até os 10px.

```css
ul.navmenu-nav>li>a:hover,
ul.navmenu-nav>li.active>a,
ul.navmenu-nav>li>a:focus {
   padding-left:15px;
   border-left: 5px solid #2E2F44;
   text-decoration: none;
   background-color: #ffffff;
   background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #2E2F44 0px, transparent 10px, transparent 10px); /* o gradiente começa no 0px e vai até o 10px começa na sua cor e termina transparente */
}
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navmenu-nav">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Item 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hugo, funcionou perfeitamente..

Comment: @RRV bom demais então, com linear-gradiente da pra fazer muita coisa legal depois da uma lida sobre essa propriedade. []'s